# Firebase function refuses to deploy with no clear reason

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, openai-api

So I have a firebase function I am trying to emulate/deploy, and no matter what I do it can't get it to works. There are logs returned by firebase but they don't provide any useful information. If anyone can see something wrong with my implementation, or can help in any way it would be greatly appreciated!

```
'use strict';
const { Configuration, OpenAIApi } = require('openai');
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const { onCall } = require('firebase-functions/v2/https');
const logger = require('firebase-functions/logger');


const configuration = new Configuration({
  apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
});

const openai = new OpenAIApi(configuration);

exports.sendMessage = onCall(
  {
    timeoutSeconds: 1200,
    region: ['europe-west1'],
    cors: ['*://localhost:*/*'],
    concurrency: 100
  },
  async (messages, context) => {
    try {
      const chatCompletion = await openai.createChatCompletion({
        model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
        temperature: 0,
        messages
      });
      const chatResponse = chatCompletion.data.choices[0].message.content;
      logger.log('Sending chat response:', chatResponse);
      return chatResponse;
    } catch (error) {
      throw new functions.https.HttpsError('internal', 'OpenAI API request failed');
    }
  }
);
```

Logs are as follows:

```
[
  {
    "textPayload": "Provided module can't be loaded.",
    "insertId": "64e4faad0007e963ad69dde6",
    "resource": {
      "type": "cloud_run_revision",
      "labels": {
        "revision_name": "sendmessage-00002-fun",
        "configuration_name": "sendmessage",
        "project_id": "book-maker-fdeee",
        "service_name": "sendmessage",
        "location": "europe-west1"
      }
    },
    "timestamp": "2023-08-22T18:13:01.518499Z",
    "labels": {
      "goog-managed-by": "cloudfunctions",
      "instanceId": "00e6760073d8279991454f68fb8db6c9f62e899dd94785580728dac9d2d7cbbeef93c153fa566b9c8bc8cf0dbf02202ed79b7455662e93f406347daa469b264df8a3"
    },
    "logName": "projects/book-maker-fdeee/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Fstderr",
    "receiveTimestamp": "2023-08-22T18:13:01.520758741Z"
  },
  {
    "textPayload": "Did you list all required modules in the package.json dependencies?",
    "insertId": "64e4faad0007e978e0df9e62",
    "resource": {
      "type": "cloud_run_revision",
      "labels": {
        "project_id": "book-maker-fdeee",
        "configuration_name": "sendmessage",
        "service_name": "sendmessage",
        "revision_name": "sendmessage-00002-fun",
        "location": "europe-west1"
      }
    },
    "timestamp": "2023-08-22T18:13:01.518520Z",
    "labels": {
      "goog-managed-by": "cloudfunctions",
      "instanceId": "00e6760073d8279991454f68fb8db6c9f62e899dd94785580728dac9d2d7cbbeef93c153fa566b9c8bc8cf0dbf02202ed79b7455662e93f406347daa469b264df8a3"
    },
    "logName": "projects/book-maker-fdeee/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Fstderr",
    "receiveTimestamp": "2023-08-22T18:13:01.520758741Z"
  },
  {
    "textPayload": "Detailed stack trace: Error: Cannot find module 'openai'",
    "insertId": "64e4faad0007e97da92db000",
    "resource": {
      "type": "cloud_run_revision",
      "labels": {
        "project_id": "book-maker-fdeee",
        "location": "europe-west1",
        "revision_name": "sendmessage-00002-fun",
        "configuration_name": "sendmessage",
        "service_name": "sendmessage"
      }
    },
    "timestamp": "2023-08-22T18:13:01.518525Z",
    "labels": {
      "instanceId": "00e6760073d8279991454f68fb8db6c9f62e899dd94785580728dac9d2d7cbbeef93c153fa566b9c8bc8cf0dbf02202ed79b7455662e93f406347daa469b264df8a3",
      "goog-managed-by": "cloudfunctions"
    },
    "logName": "projects/book-maker-fdeee/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Fstderr",
    "receiveTimestamp": "2023-08-22T18:13:01.520758741Z"
  },
  {
    "textPayload": "Require stack:",
    "insertId": "64e4faad0007e982ad534026",
    "resource": {
      "type": "cloud_run_revision",
      "labels": {
        "service_name": "sendmessage",
        "revision_name": "sendmessage-00002-fun",
        "location": "europe-west1",
        "project_id": "book-maker-fdeee",
        "configuration_name": "sendmessage"
      }
    },
    "timestamp": "2023-08-22T18:13:01.518530Z",
    "labels": {
      "goog-managed-by": "cloudfunctions",
      "instanceId": "00e6760073d8279991454f68fb8db6c9f62e899dd94785580728dac9d2d7cbbeef93c153fa566b9c8bc8cf0dbf02202ed79b7455662e93f406347daa469b264df8a3"
    },
    "logName": "projects/book-maker-fdeee/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Fstderr",
    "receiveTimestamp": "2023-08-22T18:13:01.520758741Z"
  },
  {
    "textPayload": "- /workspace/index.js",
    "insertId": "64e4faad0007e9865c493659",
    "resource": {
      "type": "cloud_run_revision",
      "labels": {
        "service_name": "sendmessage",
        "revision_name": "sendmessage-00002-fun",
        "location": "europe-west1",
        "configuration_name": "sendmessage",
        "project_id": "book-maker-fdeee"
      }
    },
    "timestamp": "2023-08-22T18:13:01.518534Z",
    "labels": {
      "instanceId": "00e6760073d8279991454f68fb8db6c9f62e899dd94785580728dac9d2d7cbbeef93c153fa566b9c8bc8cf0dbf02202ed79b7455662e93f406347daa469b264df8a3",
      "goog-managed-by": "cloudfunctions"
    },
    "logName": "projects/book-maker-fdeee/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Fstderr",
    "receiveTimestamp": "2023-08-22T18:13:01.520758741Z"
  },
  {
    "textPayload": "- /layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/loader.js",
    "insertId": "64e4faad0007e98bd97206cd",
    "resource": {
      "type": "cloud_run_revision",
      "labels": {
        "project_id": "book-maker-fdeee",
        "service_name": "sendmessage",
        "configuration_name": "sendmessage",
        "revision_name": "sendmessage-00002-fun",
        "location": "europe-west1"
      }
    },
    "timestamp": "2023-08-22T18:13:01.518539Z",
    "labels": {
      "goog-managed-by": "cloudfunctions",
      "instanceId": "00e6760073d8279991454f68fb8db6c9f62e899dd94785580728dac9d2d7cbbeef93c153fa566b9c8bc8cf0dbf02202ed79b7455662e93f406347daa469b264df8a3"
    },
    "logName": "projects/book-maker-fdeee/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Fstderr",
    "receiveTimestamp": "2023-08-22T18:13:01.520758741Z"
  },
  {
    "textPayload": "- /layers/google.nodejs.functions-framework/functions-framework/node_modules/@google-cloud/functions-framework/build/src/main.js",
    "insertId": "64e4faad0007e991801c95c5",
    "resource": {
      "type": "cloud_run_revision",
      "labels": {
        "service_name": "sendmessage",
        "project_id": "book-maker-fdeee",
        "revision_name": "sendmessage-00002-fun",
        "location": "europe-west1",
        "configuration_name": "sendmessage"
      }
    },
    "timestamp": "2023-08-22T18:13:01.518545Z",
    "labels": {
      "goog-managed-by": "cloudfunctions",
      "instanceId": "00e6760073d8279991454f68fb8db6c9f62e899dd94785580728dac9d2d7cbbeef93c153fa566b9c8bc8cf0dbf02202ed79b7455662e93f406347daa469b264df8a3"
    },
    "logName": "projects/book-maker-fdeee/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Fstderr",
    "receiveTimestamp": "2023-08-22T18:13:01.520758741Z"
  },
  {
    "textPayload": "    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1028:15)",
    "insertId": "64e4faad0007e9971608adfc",
    "resource": {
      "type": "cloud_run_revision",
      "labels": {
        "project_id": "book-maker-fdeee",
        "configuration_name": "sendmessage",
        "service_name": "sendmessage",
        "location": "europe-west1",
        "revision_name": "sendmessage-00002-fun"
      }
    },
    "timestamp": "2023-08-22T18:13:01.518551Z",
    "labels": {
      "instanceId": "00e6760073d8279991454f68fb8db6c9f62e899dd94785580728dac9d2d7cbbeef93c153fa566b9c8bc8cf0dbf02202ed79b7455662e93f406347daa469b264df8a3",
      "goog-managed-by": "cloudfunctions"
    },
    "logName": "projects/book-maker-fdeee/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Fstderr",
    "receiveTimestamp": "2023-08-22T18:13:01.520758741Z"
  },
  {
    "textPayload": "    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:873:27)",
    "insertId": "64e4faad0007e99bc4b69c05",
    "resource": {
      "type": "cloud_run_revision",
      "labels": {
        "location": "europe-west1",
        "service_name": "sendmessage",
        "revision_name": "sendmessage-00002-fun",
        "project_id": "book-maker-fdeee",
        "configuration_name": "sendmessage"
      }
    },
    "timestamp": "2023-08-22T18:13:01.518555Z",
    "labels": {
      "instanceId": "00e6760073d8279991454f68fb8db6c9f62e899dd94785580728dac9d2d7cbbeef93c153fa566b9c8bc8cf0dbf02202ed79b7455662e93f406347daa469b264df8a3",
      "goog-managed-by": "cloudfunctions"
    },
    "logName": "projects/book-maker-fdeee/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Fstderr",
    "receiveTimestamp": "2023-08-22T18:13:01.520758741Z"
  },
  {
    "textPayload": "    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1100:19)",
    "insertId": "64e4faad0007e9a005f11a36",
    "resource": {
      "type": "cloud_run_revision",
      "labels": {
        "service_name": "sendmessage",
        "project_id": "book-maker-fdeee",
        "location": "europe-west1",
        "revision_name": "sendmessage-00002-fun",
        "configuration_name": "sendmessage"
      }
    },
    "timestamp": "2023-08-22T18:13:01.518560Z",
    "labels": {
      "goog-managed-by": "cloudfunctions",
      "instanceId": "00e6760073d8279991454f68fb8db6c9f62e899dd94785580728dac9d2d7cbbeef93c153fa566b9c8bc8cf0dbf02202ed79b7455662e93f406347daa469b264df8a3"
    },
    "logName": "projects/book-maker-fdeee/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Fstderr",
    "receiveTimestamp": "2023-08-22T18:13:01.520758741Z"
  },
  {
    "textPayload": "    at require (node:internal/modules/cjs/helpers:108:18)",
    "insertId": "64e4faad0007e9a573cbb476",
    "resource": {
      "type": "cloud_run_revision",
      "labels": {
        "revision_name": "sendmessage-00002-fun",
        "project_id": "book-maker-fdeee",
        "location": "europe-west1",
        "service_name": "sendmessage",
        "configuration_name": "sendmessage"
      }
    },
    "timestamp": "2023-08-22T18:13:01.518565Z",
    "labels": {
      "goog-managed-by": "cloudfunctions",
      "instanceId": "00e6760073d8279991454f68fb8db6c9f62e899dd94785580728dac9d2d7cbbeef93c153fa566b9c8bc8cf0dbf02202ed79b7455662e93f406347daa469b264df8a3"
    },
    "logName": "projects/book-maker-fdeee/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Fstderr",
    "receiveTimestamp": "2023-08-22T18:13:01.520758741Z"
  },
  {
    "textPayload": "    at Object.<anonymous> (/workspace/index.js:2:38)",
    "insertId": "64e4faad0007e9a9ee063b93",
    "resource": {
      "type": "cloud_run_revision",
      "labels": {
        "location": "europe-west1",
        "project_id": "book-maker-fdeee",
        "service_name": "sendmessage",
        "revision_name": "sendmessage-00002-fun",
        "configuration_name": "sendmessage"
      }
    },
    "timestamp": "2023-08-22T18:13:01.518569Z",
    "labels": {
      "goog-managed-by": "cloudfunctions",
      "instanceId": "00e6760073d8279991454f68fb8db6c9f62e899dd94785580728dac9d2d7cbbeef93c153fa566b9c8bc8cf0dbf02202ed79b7455662e93f406347daa469b264df8a3"
    },
    "logName": "projects/book-maker-fdeee/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Fstderr",
    "receiveTimestamp": "2023-08-22T18:13:01.520758741Z"
  },
  {
    "textPayload": "    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1198:14)",
    "insertId": "64e4faad0007e9ae59a294e9",
    "resource": {
      "type": "cloud_run_revision",
      "labels": {
        "revision_name": "sendmessage-00002-fun",
        "service_name": "sendmessage",
        "location": "europe-west1",
        "project_id": "book-maker-fdeee",
        "configuration_name": "sendmessage"
      }
    },
    "timestamp": "2023-08-22T18:13:01.518574Z",
    "labels": {
      "instanceId": "00e6760073d8279991454f68fb8db6c9f62e899dd94785580728dac9d2d7cbbeef93c153fa566b9c8bc8cf0dbf02202ed79b7455662e93f406347daa469b264df8a3",
      "goog-managed-by": "cloudfunctions"
    },
    "logName": "projects/book-maker-fdeee/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Fstderr",
    "receiveTimestamp": "2023-08-22T18:13:01.854273028Z"
  },
  {
    "textPayload": "    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1252:10)",
    "insertId": "64e4faad0007e9b302bfa5c1",
    "resource": {
      "type": "cloud_run_revision",
      "labels": {
        "configuration_name": "sendmessage",
        "location": "europe-west1",
        "project_id": "book-maker-fdeee",
        "service_name": "sendmessage",
        "revision_name": "sendmessage-00002-fun"
      }
    },
    "timestamp": "2023-08-22T18:13:01.518579Z",
    "labels": {
      "goog-managed-by": "cloudfunctions",
      "instanceId": "00e6760073d8279991454f68fb8db6c9f62e899dd94785580728dac9d2d7cbbeef93c153fa566b9c8bc8cf0dbf02202ed79b7455662e93f406347daa469b264df8a3"
    },
    "logName": "projects/book-maker-fdeee/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Fstderr",
    "receiveTimestamp": "2023-08-22T18:13:01.854273028Z"
  },
  {
    "textPayload": "    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1076:32)",
    "insertId": "64e4faad0007e9b7cd7a32a0",
    "resource": {
      "type": "cloud_run_revision",
      "labels": {
        "location": "europe-west1",
        "project_id": "book-maker-fdeee",
        "service_name": "sendmessage",
        "configuration_name": "sendmessage",
        "revision_name": "sendmessage-00002-fun"
      }
    },
    "timestamp": "2023-08-22T18:13:01.518583Z",
    "labels": {
      "instanceId": "00e6760073d8279991454f68fb8db6c9f62e899dd94785580728dac9d2d7cbbeef93c153fa566b9c8bc8cf0dbf02202ed79b7455662e93f406347daa469b264df8a3",
      "goog-managed-by": "cloudfunctions"
    },
    "logName": "projects/book-maker-fdeee/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Fstderr",
    "receiveTimestamp": "2023-08-22T18:13:01.854273028Z"
  },
  {
    "textPayload": "    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:911:12)",
    "insertId": "64e4faad0007e9bb8d49cbfd",
    "resource": {
      "type": "cloud_run_revision",
      "labels": {
        "revision_name": "sendmessage-00002-fun",
        "location": "europe-west1",
        "configuration_name": "sendmessage",
        "service_name": "sendmessage",
        "project_id": "book-maker-fdeee"
      }
    },
    "timestamp": "2023-08-22T18:13:01.518587Z",
    "labels": {
      "instanceId": "00e6760073d8279991454f68fb8db6c9f62e899dd94785580728dac9d2d7cbbeef93c153fa566b9c8bc8cf0dbf02202ed79b7455662e93f406347daa469b264df8a3",
      "goog-managed-by": "cloudfunctions"
    },
    "logName": "projects/book-maker-fdeee/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Fstderr",
    "receiveTimestamp": "2023-08-22T18:13:01.854273028Z"
  },
  {
    "textPayload": "    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1100:19)",
    "insertId": "64e4faad0007e9bfdbe87fae",
    "resource": {
      "type": "cloud_run_revision",
      "labels": {
        "configuration_name": "sendmessage",
        "location": "europe-west1",
        "project_id": "book-maker-fdeee",
        "service_name": "sendmessage",
        "revision_name": "sendmessage-00002-fun"
      }
    },
    "timestamp": "2023-08-22T18:13:01.518591Z",
    "labels": {
      "goog-managed-by": "cloudfunctions",
      "instanceId": "00e6760073d8279991454f68fb8db6c9f62e899dd94785580728dac9d2d7cbbeef93c153fa566b9c8bc8cf0dbf02202ed79b7455662e93f406347daa469b264df8a3"
    },
    "logName": "projects/book-maker-fdeee/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Fstderr",
    "receiveTimestamp": "2023-08-22T18:13:01.854273028Z"
  },
  {
    "textPayload": "Could not load the function, shutting down.",
    "insertId": "64e4faad0007ebd50e4e07ac",
    "resource": {
      "type": "cloud_run_revision",
      "labels": {
        "project_id": "book-maker-fdeee",
        "service_name": "sendmessage",
        "configuration_name": "sendmessage",
        "revision_name": "sendmessage-00002-fun",
        "location": "europe-west1"
      }
    },
    "timestamp": "2023-08-22T18:13:01.519125Z",
    "labels": {
      "goog-managed-by": "cloudfunctions",
      "instanceId": "00e6760073d8279991454f68fb8db6c9f62e899dd94785580728dac9d2d7cbbeef93c153fa566b9c8bc8cf0dbf02202ed79b7455662e93f406347daa469b264df8a3"
    },
    "logName": "projects/book-maker-fdeee/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Fstderr",
    "receiveTimestamp": "2023-08-22T18:13:01.854273028Z"
  },
  {
    "textPayload": "Container called exit(1).",
    "insertId": "64e4faad00091bfe9e9d1725",
    "resource": {
      "type": "cloud_run_revision",
      "labels": {
        "revision_name": "sendmessage-00002-fun",
        "service_name": "sendmessage",
        "configuration_name": "sendmessage",
        "location": "europe-west1",
        "project_id": "book-maker-fdeee"
      }
    },
    "timestamp": "2023-08-22T18:13:01.596943153Z",
    "severity": "WARNING",
    "labels": {
      "instanceId": "00e6760073d8279991454f68fb8db6c9f62e899dd94785580728dac9d2d7cbbeef93c153fa566b9c8bc8cf0dbf02202ed79b7455662e93f406347daa469b264df8a3",
      "goog-managed-by": "cloudfunctions"
    },
    "logName": "projects/book-maker-fdeee/logs/run.googleapis.com%2Fvarlog%2Fsystem",
    "receiveTimestamp": "2023-08-22T18:13:01.603379423Z"
  },
  {
    "protoPayload": {
      "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.audit.AuditLog",
      "status": {
        "code": 9,
        "message": "Ready condition status changed to False for Revision sendmessage-00002-fun with message: The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.\n\nLogs URL: https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?project=book-maker-fdeee&resource=cloud_run_revision/service_name/sendmessage/revision_name/sendmessage-00002-fun&advancedFilter=resource.type%3D%22cloud_run_revision%22%0Aresource.labels.service_name%3D%22sendmessage%22%0Aresource.labels.revision_name%3D%22sendmessage-00002-fun%22 \nFor more troubleshooting guidance, see https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#container-failed-to-start"
      },
      "serviceName": "run.googleapis.com",
      "methodName": "v1",
      "resourceName": "namespaces/book-maker-fdeee/revisions/sendmessage-00002-fun",
      "response": {
        "metadata": {
          "name": "sendmessage-00002-fun",
          "namespace": "547294898932",
          "selfLink": "/apis/serving.knative.dev/v1/namespaces/547294898932/revisions/sendmessage-00002-fun",
          "uid": "3bb99d02-b603-4380-94cd-730782ce9bb6",
          "resourceVersion": "AAYDhvILqM4",
          "generation": 1,
          "creationTimestamp": "2023-08-22T18:12:54.696123Z",
          "labels": {
            "serving.knative.dev/route": "sendmessage",
            "goog-managed-by": "cloudfunctions",
            "serving.knative.dev/configuration": "sendmessage",
            "serving.knative.dev/configurationGeneration": "2",
            "goog-cloudfunctions-runtime": "nodejs16",
            "cloud.googleapis.com/location": "europe-west1",
            "serving.knative.dev/service": "sendmessage",
            "serving.knative.dev/serviceUid": "d1ac5d69-4a99-4e14-adca-31a19f4f0730",
            "run.googleapis.com/startupProbeType": "Default"
          },
          "annotations": {
            "run.googleapis.com/client-name": "cloudfunctions",
            "cloudfunctions.googleapis.com/trigger-type": "HTTP_TRIGGER",
            "serving.knative.dev/creator": "service-547294898932@gcf-admin-robot.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
            "autoscaling.knative.dev/maxScale": "100",
            "run.googleapis.com/operation-id": "8b547490-8330-4957-aef5-c34549953353",
            "run.googleapis.com/startup-cpu-boost": "true"
          },
          "ownerReferences": [
            {
              "kind": "Configuration",
              "name": "sendmessage",
              "uid": "f38d77c8-3d88-4210-b8c8-0443cd78fce5",
              "apiVersion": "serving.knative.dev/v1",
              "controller": true,
              "blockOwnerDeletion": true
            }
          ]
        },
        "apiVersion": "serving.knative.dev/v1",
        "kind": "Revision",
        "spec": {
          "containerConcurrency": 100,
          "timeoutSeconds": 1200,
          "serviceAccountName": "547294898932-compute@developer.gserviceaccount.com",
          "containers": [
            {
              "name": "send_message-1",
              "image": "europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev/book-maker-fdeee/gcf-artifacts/send_message@sha256:bb7ce7acbae5ec93b2a228cc48c3c2fb2d8b537e7805f16f667f0b1500ace254",
              "ports": [
                {
                  "name": "http1",
                  "containerPort": 8080
                }
              ],
              "env": [
                {
                  "name": "OPENAI_API_KEY",
                  "value": "I removed this cos privacy"
                },
                {
                  "name": "PROJECT_ID",
                  "value": "book-maker-fdeee"
                },
                {
                  "name": "FIREBASE_CONFIG",
                  "value": "{\"projectId\":\"book-maker-fdeee\",\"storageBucket\":\"book-maker-fdeee.appspot.com\",\"locationId\":\"europe-west\"}"
                },
                {
                  "name": "GCLOUD_PROJECT",
                  "value": "book-maker-fdeee"
                },
                {
                  "name": "EVENTARC_CLOUD_EVENT_SOURCE",
                  "value": "projects/book-maker-fdeee/locations/europe-west1/services/sendMessage"
                }
              ],
              "resources": {
                "limits": {
                  "cpu": "1",
                  "memory": "256Mi"
                }
              },
              "startupProbe": {
                "timeoutSeconds": 240,
                "periodSeconds": 240,
                "failureThreshold": 1,
                "tcpSocket": {
                  "port": 8080
                }
              }
            }
          ]
        },
        "status": {
          "observedGeneration": 1,
          "conditions": [
            {
              "type": "Ready",
              "status": "False",
              "reason": "HealthCheckContainerError",
              "message": "The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.\n\nLogs URL: https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?project=book-maker-fdeee&resource=cloud_run_revision/service_name/sendmessage/revision_name/sendmessage-00002-fun&advancedFilter=resource.type%3D%22cloud_run_revision%22%0Aresource.labels.service_name%3D%22sendmessage%22%0Aresource.labels.revision_name%3D%22sendmessage-00002-fun%22 \nFor more troubleshooting guidance, see https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#container-failed-to-start",
              "lastTransitionTime": "2023-08-22T18:13:01.615310Z"
            },
            {
              "type": "ContainerHealthy",
              "status": "False",
              "reason": "HealthCheckContainerError",
              "message": "The user-provided container failed to start and listen on the port defined provided by the PORT=8080 environment variable. Logs for this revision might contain more information.\n\nLogs URL: https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?project=book-maker-fdeee&resource=cloud_run_revision/service_name/sendmessage/revision_name/sendmessage-00002-fun&advancedFilter=resource.type%3D%22cloud_run_revision%22%0Aresource.labels.service_name%3D%22sendmessage%22%0Aresource.labels.revision_name%3D%22sendmessage-00002-fun%22 \nFor more troubleshooting guidance, see https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/troubleshooting#container-failed-to-start",
              "lastTransitionTime": "2023-08-22T18:13:01.615310Z"
            },
            {
              "type": "ResourcesAvailable",
              "status": "True",
              "lastTransitionTime": "2023-08-22T18:13:00.339582Z",
              "severity": "Error"
            },
            {
              "type": "Retry",
              "status": "True",
              "reason": "ImmediateRetry",
              "message": "System will retry after 0:00:00 from lastTransitionTime for attempt 0.",
              "lastTransitionTime": "2023-08-22T18:13:00.339582Z",
              "severity": "Info"
            }
          ],
          "logUrl": "https://console.cloud.google.com/logs/viewer?project=book-maker-fdeee&resource=cloud_run_revision/service_name/sendmessage/revision_name/sendmessage-00002-fun&advancedFilter=resource.type%3D%22cloud_run_revision%22%0Aresource.labels.service_name%3D%22sendmessage%22%0Aresource.labels.revision_name%3D%22sendmessage-00002-fun%22",
          "imageDigest": "europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev/book-maker-fdeee/gcf-artifacts/send_message@sha256:bb7ce7acbae5ec93b2a228cc48c3c2fb2d8b537e7805f16f667f0b1500ace254",
          "containerStatuses": [
            {
              "name": "send_message-1",
              "imageDigest": "europe-west1-docker.pkg.dev/book-maker-fdeee/gcf-artifacts/send_message@sha256:bb7ce7acbae5ec93b2a228cc48c3c2fb2d8b537e7805f16f667f0b1500ace254"
            }
          ]
        },
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.cloud.run.v1.Revision"
      }
    },
    "insertId": "-jemp6ud1p5s",
    "resource": {
      "type": "cloud_run_revision",
      "labels": {
        "project_id": "book-maker-fdeee",
        "configuration_name": "sendmessage",
        "service_name": "sendmessage",
        "revision_name": "sendmessage-00002-fun",
        "location": "europe-west1"
      }
    },
    "timestamp": "2023-08-22T18:13:01.635620Z",
    "severity": "ERROR",
    "logName": "projects/book-maker-fdeee/logs/cloudaudit.googleapis.com%2Fsystem_event",
    "receiveTimestamp": "2023-08-22T18:13:01.926714781Z"
  }
]
```

Comment: Maybe you could edit the question to share the logs you see anyway, even if you don't personally find them helpful? We need to see what you see is going wrong here, and the steps you take to make that happen.  You could be doing something wrong, or maybe you're misunderstanding the output.

Answer (score 0):

Your Callable Cloud Function is of 2nd gen (`const { onCall } = require('firebase-functions/v2/https');`) but you pass to the `onCall()` method parameters corresponding to 1st gen.

With 2nd gen you need to pass a unique `request` parameter which "contains data passed from the client app as well as additional context like authentication state" as explained in the [doc](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/callable?gen=2nd#write_and_deploy_the_callable_function).

The error handling code is also 1st gen code.

---

The following adaptations should do the trick (UNTESTED)

```
exports.sendMessage = onCall(
  {
    timeoutSeconds: 1200,
    region: ['europe-west1'],
    cors: ['*://localhost:*/*'],
    concurrency: 100
  },
  async (request) => { // <= Change here
    try {
      const chatCompletion = await openai.createChatCompletion({
        model: 'gpt-3.5-turbo',
        temperature: 0,
        messages: request.data.messages  // <= Change here TO BE CONFIRMED (do you pass an Object containing a messages property when calling the CF?) 
      });
      const chatResponse = chatCompletion.data.choices[0].message.content;
      logger.log('Sending chat response:', chatResponse);
      return chatResponse;
    } catch (error) {
      throw new HttpsError('internal', 'OpenAI API request failed');  // <= Change here
      // It would also be good to log or throw the error message 
      // With your code the error message received by the front-end calling the CF is always 'OpenAI API request failed' 
    }
  }
```

Comment: Hey @J.Whitehead, did my answer solved your problem?